# Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found - on ServerPilot

Tags: laravel-4

ServerPilot.io has its own composer. I have found many solutions to Laravel 4.2 Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found, but the composer (composer5.5-sp) from ServerPilot make things dont work as aspected.

This one dont works there.

1. composer5.5-sp self-update
2. composer5.5-sp update
3. composer5.5-sp update --no-scripts

How to fix this issue on ServerPilot?

Answer (score 0):

You should run composer's self-update through sudo while logged in as either "root" or "ubuntu". That is, use the following to update composer:

```
sudo composer5.5-sp self-update
```

The reason you need sudo is that composer is installed globally by ServerPilot so it takes root permissions to update it.

Comment: Very thanks, it worked. (I have entered as root user)